# Extending a UIKit delegate protocol

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add a new optional method to the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol but when the method is called, it calls the default method and not the implemented method. Is something like this possible?

```
extension UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func doneClicked(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, selectedRow: Int, inComponent component: Int) {/* default */}
}

extension UIPickerView {

    func toolbar() -> UIToolbar? {

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonClicked))
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        toolBar.setItems([spacer, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return toolBar
    }

    @objc func doneButtonClicked() {

        if let delegate = self.delegate {

            delegate.doneClicked(self, selectedRow: self.selectedRow(inComponent: 0), inComponent: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when doneClicked() gets called, only the default method in the extension gets executed. I thought that if the protocol conforming class implements the function, then Swift doesn't call the default method.

Comment: "I thought that if the protocol conforming class implements the function, then Swift doesn't call the default method" - Only if the function is actually defined in the protocol.  In your case, where it is added in an extension, the one that gets called is determined by the compile-time type of the variable which you haven't shown but I'm assuming is `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Comment: Try removing `{/* default */}`

Comment: @Koen I tried removing the curly braces but Swift doesn't allow empty body in protocol extension.

Comment: I edited my previous comment.

Comment: The interesting thing is that this paradigm works with non UIKit protocols. In other words, if I extend my own protocol, the implemented method will get called and not the default. It's only this special case using UIPickerViewDelegate.

Comment: This setup doesn't seem right. What is going to call the `doSomething()` method in the `UIPickerView` extension? `UIPickerView` certainly isn't going to know about that method.

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my code to show what I'm actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because delegate in `UIPickerView` is of type `UIPickerViewDelegate`.
Try casting like so:

```
if let delegate = self.delegate as? MyViewController {
    delegate.foo()
}
```

Comment: That was it! I kind of thought this would be automatic when assigning the view controller as the delegate. Is there any way to to make this a bit more flexible without having to cast my subclass? I created the extension thinking to reuse it in any view controller.

Comment: I think because its a protocol and not a class, the procedure you mentioned should work with classes and the `override` keyword. :)

Comment: Sure, this fixes this one specific situation but this is not a valid solution because there may be many delegates implementing `foo`, not just `MyViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid having to subclass a UIKit class, but it seems there's no other choice.

Comment: @ArbelIsraeli I've updated the code in my example to reflect what I'm actually trying to do.